# Finding values of $\theta$ for which $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ lies inside the triangle formed by $x+y=2$, $x−y=1$, and $6x+2y−\sqrt{10}​=0$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

> Find the range of values of $\theta$, such that $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$ for which $(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$ lies inside the triangle formed by $x + y = 2, x − y = 1$ and $6x + 2y − \sqrt{10} ​=0$.

Not getting any hint of how can I get the range of those points is there any short method of doing so.

I have plotted the graph and then I found out that the line $6x + 2y − \sqrt{10} ​=0$ which forms one of the sides of the triangle has $O(0,0)$ and $P(\cos \theta, \sin\theta)$ on opposite sides so applied the formula of power of point.

So $L_3(O)\cdot L_3(P)<0$ and then solved to find out the range.

If there is any short method please tell me.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the people who voted to close could leave a helpful comment saying *what* was unclear? There is a triangle, and there is a circle, and the question is asking about where they meet - what's unclear? Or am I missing something?

Comment: (p.s. @Vaibhav you should use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to make your question more readable.)

Comment: sir, but it seems clear to me , I don't understand what is not clear, people are just downvoting my question as they are unable to understand the problem, its not that easy problem its from IIT jee how would anyone without enough knowledge solve it

Comment: The issue, I believe, is simply the lack of MathJax. You have 3 reopen votes though. (If the question remains closed then you can request it be reopened [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/32975/10513).)

Comment: but Sir, I don't have 5 reputations to answer that post, also yesterday vitamin D has edited the math JAX, actually, I don't know math JAX and I am trying to learn that.

Comment: Thanks for helping Sir, I have posted that request.

Comment: Do you recognize what you get when you look at all the points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$, Vaibhav? Then you just need to find where some lines intersect that very special curve. I don't know just why users voted down, but I'm sure they had the knowledge to solve it.

Comment: thanks, sir, but can you please clarify the statement what it means about looking at points and finding the curve, please.

Comment: Have you ever worked with polar coordinates, Vaibhav? Do you know what you get when you plot all the points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ for $0\le\theta\le2\pi$? Also, if you want to be sure I see a comment intended for me, you have to put @Gerry in it, so I get notified.

Comment: @Gerry thanks sir for your advice. what would I get when I will plot all points (cos θ, sin θ)? and why can't we do it by just using the fact that point and origin lie on the same side of the line or opposite side.

Comment: Do you know any formula relating $\cos\theta$ and $\sin\theta$?

Comment: @Gerry . Yes Sir, $cos^2 \theta +sin^2\theta=1$ .But how would it help in finding values of theta inside the triangle formed by lines?

Comment: Good. So, the points $(x,y)$ given by $(x,y)=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ satisfy the equation, $x^2+y^2=1$. Now, do you recognize that equation? Do you know what it looks like, when you draw a graph of it?

Comment: @Gerry .So Sir, the region EDB, between that circle and those lines, shown in the diagram above is the range of $\theta$, and we need to find the intersection of these points to find the range of those values of $\theta$. Am I right?

Comment: No. The points $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ are *on* the circle, not inside it. In your diagram, all you want is the values of $\theta$ that give points on the arc $DE$. I think you know the value of $\theta$ that gives the point $D$. So all you have to do is figure out the coordinates of the point $E$, and from that what the corresponding value of $\theta$ is, and then you'll know the range of values of $\theta$.

Comment: @Gerry .Thank you very much sir for explaining the solution to this question.

Comment: If you can solve the problem now, then let me encourage you to write up your solution, and to post it here as an answer.

Comment: @Gerry . Sir, when I was solving this question I got into a problem.I thought the answer should be somewhere between $0$ to$\pi $ , but the answer key of this question shows that the answer should be $0 \lt \theta \lt \frac{5\pi}{3} - \arctan 3 $ . There was one more solution on the web which was https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-range-of-values-of-theta-theta-epsilon-0-2pi-for-which-cos-theta-sin/  please tell me are these correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from the diagram OP has posted, $D=(1,0)$ corresponds to $\theta=0$, so we only need to work out $E$. Now, $E$ is the intersection of $6x+2y=\sqrt{10}$ and $x^2+y^2=1$. In polar coordinates, these are $6r\cos\theta+2r\sin\theta=\sqrt{10}$ and $r=1$, so it comes down to solving $6\cos\theta+2\sin\theta=\sqrt{10}$. Noting that $6^2+2^2=40$, we divide both sides by $\sqrt{40}=2\sqrt{10}$ to get $${3\over\sqrt{10}}\cos\theta+{1\over\sqrt{10}}\sin\theta={1\over2}$$ Let $\eta=\arcsin{3\over\sqrt{10}}$ which implies $\cos\eta={1\over\sqrt{10}}$ and $\tan\eta=3$. Then we have $1/2=\sin\eta\cos\theta+\cos\eta\sin\theta=\sin(\theta+\eta)$. This is satisfied by $\theta+\eta=\pi/6$, but $\tan\eta=3>1$ implies $\eta>\pi/4$ and thus $\theta+\eta>\pi/4$, so we go to $\theta+\eta=5\pi/6$. Then, $$\theta={5\pi\over6}-\eta={5\pi\over6}-\arctan3$$